# identity of P(X) = P(X-nq) if P(X) has roots in C but is irreducible in Q

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

The question is related to ring polynoms. But to what else?

**Given:**

1. $P(X) = X^k + \cdots + a_1 X + a_0$ in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ is normed and irreducible.
2. Let $w,v \in \mathbb{C}$ be roots of $P$, such that $q:= v-w$ is in $\mathbb{Q}$.
3. Define $P_n(X) := P(X-nq)$, with $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

**Prove that:** $P_n = P$, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "I could already that $P_n \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$ and that $P_n$ is irreducible too in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$". Do you mean, you can see that it is the case?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! If you format your question using MathJax the probability that someone is going to answer your question is higher. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: The n in the definition of your polynomial is probably different from the one in $P_n$? And $P_n = P $ probably means that they are the same polynomial.

Comment: @pastudent: the exercise consists actually out of three parts, and I finished part 1, and are stuck in part 2. The sentence in "I could already..." summarizes what I successfully showed in part 1, and maybe helpful to answer the question.

Comment: @linkja: you are probably right, the "n" appears in the definition of the Polynomial P(X)= X^n ... and in the definition of P_n(X). I suspect they can be different variables actually, but as I don't know what this exercise is really about, I am not 100% sure. But thanks for showing me this, I actually didn't notice it and assumed they were different.

Comment: @linkja you are probably right concerning the meaning of "Pn(X) = P": it is to be shown, that they are the same polynomial. But I can't imagine, how P(X) and P(X-nq) can be the same thing.

Comment: Hint: see [Why is the difference of distinct roots of irreducible $f(x)\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$ never rational?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/87324/242).

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: I would say that this isn't a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87324/why-is-the-difference-of-distinct-roots-of-irreducible-fx-in-mathbbqx-ne, as this might be the final step in the solution, but it definitely isn't obvious to see how it does. Therefor it is on a very similar topic, but the angle and phrasing of the question is different enough, that this justifies it as its own question.

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to show the claim for $n = 1$, because if $P = P_1$ then $P_n(X) = P(X-nq)$ $ = P(X-q-(n-1)q)$ $ = P_1(X-(n-1)q) = P(X-(n-1)q) = P_{n-1}(X)$ and by induction $P_n = P$. To Clarify $P_n = P$, means that for all $x \in \mathbb Q$,  $P_n(x) = P(x)$. This implies that for all $x\in Q$ and $z \in \mathbb Z$, $P(x+zq) = P(x)$.

Now we take a look at any $P\in \mathbb Q[X]$ and any $q\in\mathbb Q$. Assume $P(X-q) = P(X)$, so $P(x-q) = P(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb Q$. This is clearly true if $q = 0$, so assume $q \not = 0$. Then we get, like above, that $P(x-nq) = P(x)$, so define the Polynomial $Q_{x_0}(X) = P(X)-P(x_0)$ for any $x_0\not = 0 \in \mathbb Q$. This polynomial is zero for all $x_0+nq$. Those are infinitely many different values for which $Q_{x_0}$ is zero, so $Q_{x_0}$ is the zero-polynomial $0$ and thereby $P = P(x_0)$ a constant polynomial.

With this we can see that, as constant polynomials are not irreducible, $q$ has to equal zero, so the claim now translates to:
"If $v,w$ roots of an irreducible polynomial $P\in\mathbb Q[X]$ and $v-w \in \mathbb Q$, then v = w"

Assume $v-w = q \not = 0$ then the polynomial $Q(X) = P(X)+P(X-q)$ has root $v$, but $deg(Q)<deg(P)$, this is a contradiction, as $P$ is normed and irreducible with root $v$, it has to be the minimal polynomial of $v$, but $Q$ also has $v$ as a root. Therefor $v-w = 0 \implies v = w$.

EDIT: The comment by Bill leads to an interesting [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87324/why-is-the-difference-of-distinct-roots-of-irreducible-fx-in-mathbbqx-ne) on the topic, where I got the last paragraph.

Comment: For proofs of that basic claim see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/87324/242)

Comment: I am still struggling to understand your answer, but this is a huge step forward, I had no clue where to start and now there is some light at the end of the tunnel!
Thank you very much for your efforts!!!! :) I am delighted! :-)

Comment: @JohnBlue Where are you struggling?

Comment: With "Polynomial Qx0(X)=P(X−nq)−P(x0) for any x0≠0∈Q. This polynomial is zero for all nx0. "
I don't get, why "P(X-nq) - P(X)" is the zero polynom, maybe I lack some basic theorems.

Comment: @JohnBlue I changed some things that were a bit messy, I hope that it is easier to understand now, and it shouldn't have been $nx_0$, but $x_0+nq$.

Comment: Concernig the polynomials $Q_{x_0} = P(X)-P(x_0)$, notice that we have $-P(x_0)$ the evaluation of $P$ at $x_0$ is the zero polynomial because it has infinitely many roots, which only the zero polynomial has. Alternatively you can just say that $P$ has the same value at all $x_0+nq$ which means that it has to be the constant polynomial, in characteristic 0, as any polynomial that is not constant can only take a value finitely many times. see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1137190/is-there-a-polynomial-that-has-infinitely-many-roots

Comment: thank you again!! I think I understood it now better! :-)